# Getting an error in PHP with function mcrypt_cbc()

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I am using this function I made to encrypt data:

```
function encryptCredential($data) {
$key = '9cqkTFHOfOmKn8kt&NSlIK*XMRWWx*tNY$azRdEvm2to*AQOll%8tP18g35H!zNg9l85pgnww$&q6y@1WrWZhKhx&23acq^*FWf*xdnmI%7aWwM6JQLm%tzYG^*8PIh1zD@D5QKa98Gg';
$encryptedData = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_TripleDES, substr($key,0,32), pad($data), MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, substr($key,32,16));
return base64_encode($encryptedData);
}
```

PHP then gives me this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  mcrypt_cbc() [<a href='function.mcrypt-cbc'>function.mcrypt-cbc</a>]: The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize in /home/xxxxx/public_html/libraries/global.inc.php on line xx
```

Is my key too long? How many characters should it be?

Comment: `//start pad unpad functions
function pad($text) {
  // Add a single 0x80 byte and let PHP pad with 0x00 bytes.
  return pack("a*H2", $text, "80");
  //return $text;
}
function unpad($text) {
  // Return all but the trailing 0x80 from text that had the 0x00 bytes removed
  return substr(rtrim($text, "\0"), 0, -1);
  //return trim($text);
}
//end pad unpad functions`

Comment: From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-cbc.php) : "This function should not be used anymore, see mcrypt_generic() and mdecrypt_generic() for replacements."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should heed deprecation warnings when you find them.

That said, the block size of [TripleDES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TripleDES) is 8 bytes, but you're supplying 16 bytes for the IV. Change your `substr($key,32,16)` to `substr($key,32,8)` and it ought to work.

But I'd still recommend moving to the new API.

Answer (score 1):

The block size, and so the IV size, is 8 bytes. The key size 24 bytes.

You can get this information with `mcrypt_get_iv_size` and `mcrypt_get_key_size`.

In CBC mode the IV must be unique and unpredictable for each encrypted message. Use `mcrypt_create_iv(8)` to create a suitable one. It needn't be secret, so it can be stored with the encrypted message.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are using seems to be depricated, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-cbc.php

> This function should not be used anymore, see mcrypt_generic() and mdecrypt_generic() for replacements.

Try those functions instead and see if you still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I will fix the IV later but here are my new functions for anyone seeing this page and needing them:

`//start encryptCredential function
function encryptCredential($data) {
$key = '9cqkTFHOfOmKn8kt&NSlIK*XMRWWx*tNY$azRdEvm2to*AQOll%8tP18g35H!zNg9l85pgnww$&q6y@1WrWZhKhx&23acq^*FWf*xdnmI%7aWwM6JQLm%tzYG^*8PIh1zD@D5QKa98Gg';
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_blowfish, '', 'cbc', '');
mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, substr($key,8,56), substr($key,32,8));
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($cipher, pad($data));
mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
//end encryptCredential function

//start decryptCredential function
function decryptCredential($data) {
$encryptedData = base64_decode($data);
$key = '9cqkTFHOfOmKn8kt&NSlIK*XMRWWx*tNY$azRdEvm2to*AQOll%8tP18g35H!zNg9l85pgnww$&q6y@1WrWZhKhx&23acq^*FWf*xdnmI%7aWwM6JQLm%tzYG^*8PIh1zD@D5QKa98Gg';
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_blowfish, '', 'cbc', '');
mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, substr($key,8,56), substr($key,32,8));
$decrypted = unpad(mdecrypt_generic($cipher, $encryptedData));
mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
return $decrypted;
}
//end decryptCredential function`

Comment: And here is a list of modules with iv and key sizes:

Comment: cast-128, iv:8, key:16
gost, iv:8, key:32
rijndael-128, iv:16, key:32
twofish, iv:16, key:32
arcfour, iv:, key:
cast-256, iv:16, key:32
loki97, iv:16, key:32
rijndael-192, iv:24, key:32
saferplus, iv:16, key:32
wake, iv:, key:
blowfish-compat, iv:8, key:56
des, iv:8, key:8
rijndael-256, iv:32, key:32
serpent, iv:16, key:32
xtea, iv:8, key:16
blowfish, iv:8, key:56
enigma, iv:, key:
rc2, iv:8, key:128
tripledes, iv:8, key:24